# Can't access my main domain ("Couldn't resolve host")

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, redirect, dns-zone, domains

I have a domain ([bydorian.com](http://www.bydorian.com)) and today I tried to remove the `www` at the beginning.

But now the sub-domain works (www.bydorian.com) but not the main domain (bydorian.com).

The curl response is : `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'bydorian.com'`

Here is the important part of my zone file :

```
* 10800 IN A 46.105.178.101
dev 10800 IN A 46.105.178.101
www 10800 IN A 46.105.178.101
```

And my virtualhosts :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName bydorian.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/www

        <Directory /var/www/www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass /transmission http://localhost:9091/transmission
        ProxyPassReverse /transmission http://localhost:9091/transmission

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dev
        ServerName dev.bydorian.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a plain

```
 IN A 46.105.178.101
```

line too, because

```
 * IN A 46.105.178.101
```

only maches to subdomains.

Comment: Like this : `@ 10800 IN A 46.105.178.101`?

Comment: Like this: `10800 IN A 46.105.178.101`